# I need to get the commandButton that is inside the plus sign call the onclick function without it being clicked and the button to be insivible

Tags: visualforce

I need to get the commandButton to work when I press the plus sign on the row.
I need the commandButton to be insivible. I think I might need some javaScript for this.

Here is my visualForce page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="myEmployeeController3">
    <apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
        <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

        <style>
            p { font-weight: bold; }
            p {font-size: 15px;}
            h1,h2 {display:block;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;}
            h1 {font-size: 20px;}
            h2 {font-size: 16px;}
            #inputSection {text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 10px;}

        </style>
        <script>
        function switchMenu(obj,obj1,obj2) 
        {
            var el = document.getElementById(obj);                                       
            if ( el.style.display != 'none' ) {
                el.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                el.style.display = '';
            }
            var e2 = document.getElementById(obj1);                                       
            if ( e2.style.display != 'none' ) {
                e2.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                e2.style.display = '';
            }
            var e3 = document.getElementById(obj2);                                       
            if ( e2.style.display != 'none' ) {
                e3.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                e3.style.display = '';
            }

        }
        </script>
        <apex:form >
            <h1>Permissions Inspector</h1>
            <h2>Enter Object API Name</h2>

            <div id="inputSection">
                <apex:inputText value="{!SObjectName}"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!actionSupMethod}" reRender="test2" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
            <apex:actionfunction action="{!submitLead}" name="myFunction" reRender="PBS1">
                <apex:param name="recordId" value="" assignTo="{!recordId}"/>
            </apex:actionfunction>
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="test2" value="{!objectout}" var="cus" >
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">                                        
                            THE RESULTS ARE                                                                             
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputpanel id="plusimage">
                            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Plus_Image}" onclick="switchMenu
                                                                               ('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.minusimage}','{!$Component.plusimage}')" title="Expand"/> 
                       </apex:outputpanel>
                        <apex:outputpanel id="minusimage" style="display:none;">
                            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Minus_Image}"
                                        onclick="switchMenu('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.plusimage}','{!$Component.minusimage}')" title="Collapse"/>
                        </apex:outputpanel>

                        <apex:outputpanel id="inlinetablesec" style="display:none;">
                            <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNum"/>
                            <apex:repeat var="count" value="{!cus.Parent.Profile.Name}">
                                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
                                <!--<apex:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="myFunction('{!cus.ParentId}'); return false;" reRender="PBS1"/>-->
                                </apex:repeat> 
                            <apex:outputText rendered="{!rowNum=0}">  Element Set Null </apex:outputText>

                            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!dataMap}" var="tm" rendered="{!rowNum>0}" id="PBS1">

                                <apex:column headerValue="Field names">
                                     {!dataMap}

                                </apex:column>
                            </apex:pageblocktable>
                        </apex:outputpanel>     
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Object" value="{!cus.SObjectType}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Read" value="{!cus.PermissionsRead}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Parent ID" value="{!cus.ParentId}"/> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Edit" value="{!cus.PermissionsEdit}"/>p
                    <apex:column headerValue="Delete" value="{!cus.PermissionsDelete}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="ViewAll" value="{!cus.PermissionsViewAllRecords}"/> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="ModifyAll" value="{!cus.PermissionsModifyAllRecords}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:form>

    </apex:page>
```

Here is my Controller

```
public with sharing class myEmployeeController3 {
    public String SObjectName{get;set;}
    public List<ObjectPermissions> objectout{get;set;}
    public List<FieldPermissions> fieldPerms{get;set;}
    public String recordId{get; set;}


     //public ID recor = ID.valueOf(recordId);

   // public Map<ObjectPermissions,List<FieldPermissions>> dataMap{get;set;}
    public Map<Id,ObjectPermissions> objMap{get;set;}
    public Map<Id,List<FieldPermissions>> dataMap{get;set;}

    public void submitLead() {
        System.debug('recordID ' + recordId);

        fieldPerms = [SELECT Field, ParentId
                     FROM FieldPermissions
                     WHERE ParentId=:recordId AND SObjectType =:SObjectName 
                     ORDER BY Field DESC];

        dataMap = new Map<ID,List<FieldPermissions>>();

        if(fieldPerms != null)
        {   
            System.debug('fieldPerms ' + fieldPerms);

            for(FieldPermissions fp :fieldPerms)
            {
                if(!dataMap.containsKey(recordId))
                {
                    //needs to be number - is coming as text
                    dataMap.put(recordId,new List<FieldPermissions>());
                    dataMap.get(recordId).add(fp);
                }
                else
                {
                    dataMap.get(recordId).add(fp);
                }



            }
        }

        System.debug('dataMap ' + dataMap);
    }
    public myEmployeeController3(){
        recordId= '';
    }


    Public void actionSupMethod(){
        objectout =  [SELECT ParentId, Parent.Profile.Name, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsDelete,
                      PermissionsViewAllRecords,PermissionsModifyAllRecords
                      FROM ObjectPermissions 
                      WHERE SObjectType = :SObjectName AND (PermissionsRead = true OR PermissionsCreate = true 
                                                            OR PermissionsEdit = true OR PermissionsDelete = true 
                                                            OR PermissionsViewAllRecords = true OR PermissionsModifyAllRecords = true)
                      ORDER BY Parent.IsOwnedByProfile ASC];

         objMap = new Map<Id,ObjectPermissions>();
        if(objectout != null)
        {
            for(ObjectPermissions op :objectout)
            {
                objMap.put(op.ParentId,op);
            }
        }
        System.debug('objMap values ' + objMap);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're already familiar with action functions. So, since you wanted to hide the commandButton in the first place, I don't see any reason to keep it. So we could remove the commandButton:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!actionSupMethod}" reRender="test2" value="Submit"/>
```

and use action function instead:

```
<apex:actionfunction action="{!actionSupMethod}" name="actionSupAF" reRender="test2"/>
```

Your plus sign element already calls a js function. So, to keep it we will create a new function that will call it first, and then our new Action Function:

```
function plusClick(obj,obj1,obj2) {
  switchMenu(obj,obj1,obj2);
  actionSupAF();
}
```

And finally change your plus image to call the new function:

```
<apex:image url="{!$Resource.Plus_Image}" onclick="plusClick('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.minusimage}','{!$Component.plusimage}')" title="Expand"/>
```

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120177/incorrect-parameter-type-for-subscript-expected-number-received-text-error?noredirect=1#comment169544_120177

Answer (score 0):

Hide the command button inside a div and display it when the plus sign is clicked through a javascript.

```
<div id="buttonDiv" style="display:none;">
   <apex:commandButton action="{!whatever}" value="Click Me"/>
</div>
//javascript function can be like this
function showButton()
{
  document.getElementById("buttonDiv").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Hope this helps.