# Using onClick instead of commandButton (follow-up)

Tags: visualforce

Referring to: [I need to get the commandButton that is inside the plus sign call the onclick function without it being clicked and the button to be insivible](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120519/i-need-to-get-the-commandbutton-that-is-inside-the-plus-sign-call-the-onclick-fu)

Looking for same answer --although poster, before removal by moderator, claimed he figured it out ..but did not post his own answer :-(

Note the VF and controller here uses a commandButton (posted there but commented out) where poster and myself are looking for an alternative solution whereby the click on **plusimage** executes submitLead() and reRenders PBS1 (no commandButton needed).  On a positive note, the data required for this VF example is SF permissions so easy enough to reproduce (*Preview* works!).

Even with using the commandButton, the "Field names" results are not showing the field names as expected (jQuery datamap issue?).  Nevertheless, I have a similar use-case that requires this same **plusimage** drill-down.

Here's my current VF page that uses `<apex:actionfunction>` but problem exists -- how to prevent the same data from appearing when multiple table rows are selected with "+"

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="myEmployeeController3">
    <apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
        <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

        <style>
            p { font-weight: bold; }
            p {font-size: 15px;}
            h1,h2 {display:block;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;}
            h1 {font-size: 20px;}
            h2 {font-size: 16px;}
            #inputSection {text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 10px;}

        </style>
        <script>
        function switchMenu(obj,obj1,obj2) 
        {
            var el = document.getElementById(obj);                                       
            if ( el.style.display != 'none' ) {
                el.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                el.style.display = '';
            }
            var e2 = document.getElementById(obj1);                                       
            if ( e2.style.display != 'none' ) {
                e2.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                e2.style.display = '';
            }
            var e3 = document.getElementById(obj2);                                       
            if ( e2.style.display != 'none' ) {
                e3.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                e3.style.display = '';
            }
        }

        function plusClick(obj,obj1,obj2,recordId) {
            switchMenu(obj,obj1,obj2);
            //alert(recordId);
            submitLead(recordId);
        }

        </script>
        <apex:form >
            <h1>Permissions Inspector</h1>
            <h2>Enter Object API Name</h2>

            <div id="inputSection" >
                <apex:inputText value="{!SObjectName}"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!actionSupMethod}" reRender="test2" value="Submit"/>
            </div>

        <!--<apex:image url="{!$Resource.Plus_Image}" onclick="switchMenu
                                                  ('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.minusimage}','{!$Component.plusimage}')" title="Expand"/> -->
            <apex:actionFunction name="submitLead" action="{!submitLead}" reRender="PBS1" >
                <apex:param id="aname" name="recordId" value=""/>
            </apex:actionFunction>

            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="test2" value="{!objectout}" var="cus" >
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">                                        
                            THE RESULTS ARE                                                                             
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputpanel id="plusimage">
                            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Plus_Image}" 
                                onclick="plusClick('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.minusimage}','{!$Component.plusimage}','{!cus.ParentId}'); return false;" title="Expand" />
                        </apex:outputpanel>
                        <apex:outputpanel id="minusimage" style="display:none;">
                            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Minus_Image}"
                               onclick="switchMenu('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.plusimage}','{!$Component.minusimage}')" title="Collapse"/>
                        </apex:outputpanel>

                        <apex:outputpanel id="inlinetablesec" style="display:none;">
                            <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNum"/>
                            <apex:repeat var="count" value="{!cus.Parent.Profile.Name}">
                                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
                                <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="myFunction('{!cus.ParentId}'); return false;" reRender="PBS1"/> -->
                                </apex:repeat> 
                            <apex:outputText rendered="{!rowNum=0}">  Element Set Null </apex:outputText>

                            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!dataMap}" var="tm" rendered="{!rowNum>0}" id="PBS1">

                                <apex:column headerValue="Field names">
                                     {!dataMap}

                                </apex:column>
                            </apex:pageblocktable>

                        </apex:outputpanel>     
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Object" value="{!cus.SObjectType}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Read" value="{!cus.PermissionsRead}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Parent ID" value="{!cus.ParentId}"/> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Edit" value="{!cus.PermissionsEdit}"/>p
                    <apex:column headerValue="Delete" value="{!cus.PermissionsDelete}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="ViewAll" value="{!cus.PermissionsViewAllRecords}"/> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="ModifyAll" value="{!cus.PermissionsModifyAllRecords}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:form>

    </apex:page>
```

Comment: You're more likely to get useful answers if you include your own code/markup.

Comment: I would not have used a command button. Simply add an onclick to the element and have it call and action function.

Comment: @Eric, I believe that's the proper path but I'm unable to get the actionfunction to work correctly.  I've tried what was proposed in original (linked) post but this seems to simply lock plusimage. Can you post your use of actionfunction?

Comment: @Eric, I edited question to include my current VF that uses action function

Comment: You are not actually calling your actionFunction in this markup. As rendered in the page it is `myFunction(recordId)`, like you've got on the commented out commandButton.

Comment: @MarkPond, edited VF in question to call action function but still no joy. Need a hint or more.

Comment: Corrected the actionfunction in question's VF (my JS was incorrectly nested).  Now that the actionfunction is executing, I'm wondering how to prevent the same data appearing when more-than-one row is clicked

Comment: @Senechaux - So do you still need an answer for this question? If not maybe make a different question for your last comment and delete this question.

Comment: The VF in the question resolves the use of actionfunction.  New question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187515/how-to-rerender-just-one-pageblocktable-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final VF page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="myEmployeeController3">
    <apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
        <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

        <style>
            p { font-weight: bold; }
            p {font-size: 15px;}
            h1,h2 {display:block;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;}
            h1 {font-size: 20px;}
            h2 {font-size: 16px;}
            #inputSection {text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 10px;}

        </style>
        <script>
        function switchMenu(obj,obj1,obj2) 
        {
            var el = document.getElementById(obj);                                       
            if ( el.style.display != 'none' ) {
                el.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                el.style.display = '';
            }
            var e2 = document.getElementById(obj1);                                       
            if ( e2.style.display != 'none' ) {
                e2.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                e2.style.display = '';
            }
            var e3 = document.getElementById(obj2);                                       
            if ( e2.style.display != 'none' ) {
                e3.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                e3.style.display = '';
            }
        }

        function plusClick(obj,obj1,obj2,recordId) {
            switchMenu(obj,obj1,obj2);
            //alert(recordId);
            submitLead(recordId);
        }

        </script>
        <apex:form >
            <h1>Permissions Inspector</h1>
            <h2>Enter Object API Name</h2>

            <div id="inputSection" >
                <apex:inputText value="{!SObjectName}"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!actionSupMethod}" reRender="test2" value="Submit"/>
            </div>

        <!--<apex:image url="{!$Resource.Plus_Image}" onclick="switchMenu
                                                  ('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.minusimage}','{!$Component.plusimage}')" title="Expand"/> -->
            <apex:actionFunction name="submitLead" action="{!submitLead}" reRender="PBS1" >
                <apex:param id="aname" name="recordId" value=""/>
            </apex:actionFunction>

            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="test2" value="{!objectout}" var="cus" >
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">                                        
                            THE RESULTS ARE                                                                             
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputpanel id="plusimage">
                            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Plus_Image}" 
                                onclick="plusClick('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.minusimage}','{!$Component.plusimage}','{!cus.ParentId}'); return false;" title="Expand" />
                        </apex:outputpanel>
                        <apex:outputpanel id="minusimage" style="display:none;">
                            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Minus_Image}"
                               onclick="switchMenu('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.plusimage}','{!$Component.minusimage}')" title="Collapse"/>
                        </apex:outputpanel>

                        <apex:outputpanel id="inlinetablesec" style="display:none;">
                            <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNum"/>
                            <apex:repeat var="count" value="{!cus.Parent.Profile.Name}">
                                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
                                <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="myFunction('{!cus.ParentId}'); return false;" reRender="PBS1"/> -->
                                </apex:repeat> 
                            <apex:outputText rendered="{!rowNum=0}">  Element Set Null </apex:outputText>

                            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!dataMap}" var="tm" rendered="{!rowNum>0}" id="PBS1">

                                <apex:column headerValue="Field names">
                                     {!dataMap}

                                </apex:column>
                            </apex:pageblocktable>

                        </apex:outputpanel>     
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Object" value="{!cus.SObjectType}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Read" value="{!cus.PermissionsRead}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Parent ID" value="{!cus.ParentId}"/> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Edit" value="{!cus.PermissionsEdit}"/>p
                    <apex:column headerValue="Delete" value="{!cus.PermissionsDelete}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="ViewAll" value="{!cus.PermissionsViewAllRecords}"/> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="ModifyAll" value="{!cus.PermissionsModifyAllRecords}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:form>

    </apex:page>
```